# Creating a function to return a column

Tags: r, plyr, sumifs, dplyr

I need to create a function to return a column given in to the function as an argument. Eg

```
fun = function (parameter) {
result = get(paste0("dataframe","parameter"))
return(result) }
```

so that if I would use `fun (columnnamethatexists)` it would return `dataframe$columnnamethatexists`

Currently, what it does is return dataframe$parameter does not exist, no matter what I put in as input.

Sorry for a stupid Q which is probably a replicate, yet I could not find it.

Thanks!

Comment: You generally would not use a function for this: dataframe[,"parameter"] will return what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataframe <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = LETTERS[1:10])

fun <- function(val) {
  dataframe[, val]
}

fun("a")
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
fun("b")
#  [1] A B C D E F G H I J
# Levels: A B C D E F G H I J
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the df should also be an argument of your function. This solution always return the column in the form of a data.frame.

So :

```
fun <- function(df, col){
  df[col]
}
fun(iris, "Sepal.Length")
    Sepal.Length
1            5.1
2            4.9
3            4.7
4            4.6
5            5.0
6            5.4
7            4.6
8            5.0
...
```

You can also do it with `tidyeval`, in `rlang` and with `dplyr` :

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

fun <- function(df, col){
  col <- enquo(col)
  df %>% select(!!col)
}

fun(iris, Sepal.Length)
```

Best,

Colin

Comment: Your NSE/quosury thing exists in base R already: `subset(iris, select = Sepal.Length)`. Both yours and `subset` return a DF, though, while OP seems to want `drop=TRUE` / to get the column itself. Also, I guess `dplyr::select(iris, Sepal.Length)` already does what your fun does?